# Fontawesome 5 not displaying when using fa-solid.js

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I have an issue with displaying fontawesome when using the fa-solid.js instead of fontawesome-all.js

documentation states to use fas or fa for prefix, which I do, but still, nothing is showing unless I use the all.js package.

Am I missing something?

Comment: "Am I missing something?" - probably. But that is hard to tell without seeing your code (or the generated .html)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this is old, but I just encountered the same problem.

What FA documentation is not telling you is how to load only one of the icon library (eg "solid").

**Solution:**

- either you load "fontawesome-all.js"
- or you load "fa-solid.js" **AND "fontawesome.js"**

(Of course, you can load the ".min" version of all of these scripts to gain some loading time.)

Comment: this is actually not very impressive from them but yea, I figured it out after trying multiple time